# Tzitzis on a cape?

Tags: clothing, tzitzis

So I recently saw a man wearing a cape as part of a costume. I noticed that he had attached Tzitzis to the four corners of this cape.

It must be that tzitzis are required because it is a 4 cornered garment. On the other hand, he was already wearing a "talis koton" (garment with four corners worn to obigate the wearer in the mitzva of tzitzis.

My question is: Do you have to put Tzitzis on a cape if you are already wearing a "talis koton"?

Comment: Your second line is implying "does one need _tzitziyos_ on all 4-cornered garments or just one at a time?" and the last part implies both "does one need _tzitziyos_ on a cape?" and "does one need _tzitziyos_ on a costume?". I think that's two different questions, probably not three. Consider splitting it up.

Comment: Please verify if the edit is consistent to your question

Comment: Since one wears a tallis gadol as well as tzitzis (tallis katan), then the implication is that each four cornered garment must have tzitzis on it. The only question left is if this applies to a cape.